# Fill an area between two curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

I am trying to fill the small area between the two circles, between paths A and B (in the code), could you help me, please?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [domain=0:360] plot [smooth] ({1.5*cos(\x)}, {1.5*sin(\x)});
\draw [domain=0:360] plot [smooth] ({2.55*cos(\x)}, {2.55*sin(\x)});
\draw [name path=A](2.20836478,1.275)to[out=-60,in=-20](1.299038106,0.75);
\draw [name path=B] (2.20836478,-1.275)to[out=60,in=20](1.299038106,-0.75);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, The `fill` operation applies to **one** Ti*k*Z statement in which you must have the whole path that you want to fill (Ti*k*Z closes it with a straight line in case it wasn't already closed). I didn't manage to get a perfect result with the parametric plots connected with the `to` operation—in my best attempt, there was a thin remaining straight line. However, the following code performs the same geometric construction using the `arc` operation, which gives a better result than `plot` (the resulting output is closer to actual circle arcs than the interpolated plots, AFAIK). Note the convenient use of polar coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (30:2.55cm)
  arc[start angle=30, end angle=330, radius=2.55cm]
  to[out=60, in=20] (330:1.5cm)
  arc[start angle=330, end angle=30, radius=1.5cm]
  to[out=-20, in=-60] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From a previous question, I seem to recall you wanted to fill this “bean” with a pattern, so here it is, using `pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=4pt]}` from the `patterns.meta` Ti*k*Z library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=4pt]}] (30:2.55cm)
  arc[start angle=30, end angle=330, radius=2.55cm]
  to[out=60, in=20] (330:1.5cm)
  arc[start angle=330, end angle=30, radius=1.5cm]
  to[out=-20, in=-60] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S.: neither my code nor yours uses `pgfplots`, therefore I removed the `\usepackage{pgfplots}` and `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` lines.